# Trying to understand how a Controller uses a Plugin/Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok so I am using some module/lib/plugin (not sure of the exact name), let's say its a authentication/authorization plugin like: http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController


    some_module_name_here


end
```

Now just from adding the code above 'some_module_name_here', I can access to methods from that module.

What is that line of code doing that gives me access to methods/objects from the module?

Is that declaring a variable like in say java/c#:

```
public SomeModule _someModule;
```

I know that plugins/modules basically extend the class under the covers, but how does it do this with a single line of code?

**Is it called in the constructor somehow?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a ruby plugin, and load it into the rails app via environment.rb, bundler, or a `require` call, the methods are loaded as "modules" that can be called.  The ones that act like you're talking about will have an extra method called `acts_as_list` or something similar.  All that method does is *include* the methods of the module into the class where that line was called.

Here's an example, which you could include in your app's lib folder and play with:

```
module Bellmyer
  module Pointless
    def self.included(base)
      base.extend PointlessMethods
    end

    module PointlessMethods
      def acts_as_pointless
        unless included_modules.include? InstanceMethods
          extend ClassMethods
          include InstanceMethods
        end
      end
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def pointless_class?
        true
      end
    end

    module InstanceMethods
      def pointless_instance?
        true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The module is available to any ruby class in your app, but the methods don't actually get loaded until you call `acts_as_pointless`, which then includes and extends your class with the methods listed.  Only the `acts_as_pointless` method is immediately available to the model.  This is the standard pattern for an ActiveRecord plugin.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how it works.

When the plugin or gem is loaded it adds a class method to, in this case, ApplicationController named `some_module_name`. When you call that methods, a bunch of other class and instance methods are included.

Check out your favourite gem or plugin to see how they do it exactly.